Unzip file in stream request gives UnexpectedSignatureError
Trying to get a file export from a request which is in zip format. I want to download line by line since later I will be uploading to cloud storage and do not want to store the whole file in memory.
I tried the following:
with requests.get(export_url, stream=True) as response:
    for file_name, file_size, unzipped_chunks in stream_unzip(response.iter_lines()):
        for chunk in unzipped_chunks:
            print(chunk)

However I am getting the following error that I am not sure how to solve or what it means.
UnexpectedSignatureError: b'<htm'


You're downloading (streaming) a zip file, and you are treating the chunks as though they are seperate zip files too? Stop trying to unzip byte chunks.

"line by line" in a zip file seems unlikely to work. Why not stream to a file (rather than keeping it in memory) then use your system's unzipping tool (e.g., gunzip) via a subprocess to limit Python's memory usage

@trazoM isn't that the whole purpose of the stream_unzip library? That I can treat chunks of zip and unzip them without having to load the whole file

@SIGHUP I should not store any files in the system since it is based on pods that might be used by other processes

@Juanjo In that case I believe your requirement is impossible to fulfil

@SIGHUP It seems like this answer from trazoM is working just fine

@Juanjo You said in your question that you want to "download" then upload to cloud storage. How does that solution satisfy your requirement? All it does is write the content to stdout

Try this:
from stream_unzip import stream_unzip
import httpx

def zipped_chunks():
    # Iterable that yields the bytes of a zip file
    with httpx.stream('GET', 'https://www.example.com/my.zip') as r:
        yield from r.iter_bytes(chunk_size=65536)

for file_name, file_size, unzipped_chunks in stream_unzip(zipped_chunks()):
    for chunk in unzipped_chunks:
        print(chunk)


Great answer, this seems to be working. However, I do have one question, Why did you define the chunk_size in 65536? Is there a way of knowing which value do I need?

@Juanjo 65536 is the number or bytes we want to process at a time so we don't load/stream all the data into memory all at once. You can experiment with different numbers. Usually, by design, computers love numbers that are powers of 2.
65536 is 2^16
